# Does the central limit theorem and confidence intervals apply to any distribution, including memoryless distributions?

Tags: probability

Is it possible to assign a 1 or a 0 to values in any distribution, be it a memoryless power law or pareto distribution to match some criteria such as if a value is under 10 it gets a 1, otherwise it gets a 0, then to calculate the average of this distribution within a desired confidence interval, such that it will give you the probability of any random value from the distribution matching your criteria? In other words is it possible to calculate the probability of any random value from non-normal memoryless distributions matching some arbitrary criteria by calculating a success rate confidence interval?